# How to deploy smart contracts from other accounts using javascript?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethers.js

How can we deploy contracts using web3.js or ethers.js just like thirdweb does?

I create a contract on web3.js then used the deploy function with send but then alchemy gave an error that it can't access users private key

Then I tried signing a transaction and then send Raw Transaction but this was not working, any solutions to this?

Comment: What error did you get when submitting a signed transaction?

Answer (score 0):

With Ethers you can use a [ContractFactory](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/#ContractFactory--creating) which is connected to the signer that should deploy the contract.

A signer can for example be a Ethers [Wallet](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet).

Comment: But I don't have private key of that user, is there a way, I can let them sign contract deployment with Metamask?

Comment: you can use the [Web3Provider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/other/#Web3Provider) and pass `window.ethereum` (the injected MM connector) to it. Then you can get the signer with [getSigner](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/#JsonRpcProvider-getSigner). This signer can be used with the ContractFactory as mentioned above.

Comment: I have created a proxy contract that uses the `new` solidity keyword to create a new copy of that contract and the call that function from ethers js